# How could i pass parametres to procedure, activated throught button click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a blog. On it's main page there is a list of topics. I would like to create a button, which would allow user to delete the topic (i know ID of every topic in a list, and that ID is a key field in the database).

**Views/Home/Index:**

```
   @{
    if (ViewBag.userIsModerator)
        using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteTopic", "Home", new { topicId = item.ID }))
        {
            <input type = "submit" value = "Delete topic" />
        }
    }
```

The following procedure is launching after the click on submit.

**Controllers/HomeController:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteTopic(int topicId)
{
    db.DeleteTopic(topicId);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

My problem is to pass a topic's ID into controller, because **new { topicId = item.ID }** is a source of the error. Does anybody know, how to reach this problem, without **new { topicId = item.ID }**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your using you could use a Hidden Field.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="hidden" name="topicId" value="5" />
   ...
}
```